# /usr/bin/env: 'python': No such file or directory despite installs of python 2.7 and 3.8

Tags: virtualbox, python

I am running ubuntu on a the Oracle VM Virtualbox and have installed both python 3.8 and 2.7.

```
whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python3.8 /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.8
```

yet when running a tool that requires python I get:

```
/usr/bin/env: 'python': No such file or directory
```

When opening the script called by the tool is is headed with and then states the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# Seems to work with Python 2.x, x>=6
```

I have tried the following:

```
alias python=python3
alias python='/usr/bin/python3'
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

How do I solve python not being found?

Comment: We don't know your release, however most (*if not all*) Ubuntu releases include python already installed. (20.04 won't include `python2` by default, and I'm unsure about *yy* or specialist releases), so what OS & release are you using? and why not use default python?

Comment: The OS the VM is running of is Windows. The Ubuntu release is 20.04. I tried using the default python but that is python3 (I think) and required the use of python3 to work it seemed. The tool indicated python 2 would work so I tried to download that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use the following to ensure python calls are directed to python3

```
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
```